# How to install or make working keras_retinanet.utils.gpu module?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, faster-rcnn, retinanet

I am trying to train M-RCNN using Keras and RetinaNet as in the Keras founder's example. I installed retinanet package but this module isn't found. May be it is related to that my TF doesn't use GPU? How to check that?

```
from keras_retinanet.utils.gpu import setup_gpu
    Traceback (most recent call last):

      File "<ipython-input-2-1f3ae263a7c6>", line 1, in <module>
        from keras_retinanet.utils.gpu import setup_gpu

    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras_retinanet.utils.gpu'
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to install some submodules. The beginning of this code may help you https://www.kaggle.com/labintsevai/keras-retinanet-submission